# Modify property on SKNode while moving

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sknode

I have a subclass of SKNode that acts as my "creature". These move about the scene automatically using SKActions. I'm interested in modifying (decreasing) an 'energy' property (Int) as the creature moves.

The creature isn't guaranteed to move the entire length of the move SKAction (it can be interrupted), so calculating the total distance and then decreasing the property as soon as it starts moving isn't ideal. I'd essentially like to say "for every 1 second the node is moving, decrease the energy property".

How can I do this? I'm at a loss! Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `GameScene.swift` class you have an `update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval)` function that can track one second intervals. Add a class level variable to hold the accumulated time, then check every one second if your creature is running its action.

```
class GameScene : SKScene {
    private var accumulatedTime: TimeInterval = 0

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {    
        if (self.accumulatedTime == 0) {
            self.accumulatedTime = currentTime
        }

        if currentTime - self.accumulatedTime > 1 {
            if creatureNode.action(forKey: "moveActionKey") != nil {
               // TODO: Update energy status
            }

            // Reset counter
            self.accumulatedTime = currentTime
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you make the time interval a variable, then you can also adjust it on the fly:  `let energyUpdateTime : TimeInterval = 1` and then`if currentTime - self.accumulatedTime > energyUpdateTime`

Answer (score 2):

If you know the energy property, then just use that as your duration, and use the `move(by:` SKAction.

If you want your energy to deplete with it,  use an `SKAction.customAction` in a group to decreate it

```
var previousTime = 0
let move = SKAction.moveBy(x:dx * energy,y:dy * energy,duration:energy)
let depreciateEnergy = SKAction.customAction(withDuration:energy,{(node,time) in node.energy -= (time - previuosTime);previousTime = time}) 
let group = [move,depreciateEnergy]
character.run(group,withKey:"character")
```

Now if at any time you need to stop the action,  just call `character.removeActionForKey("character")`, and your energy meter will stay at whatever energy is remaining.