# How to call a function every 3 seconds using Swift Spritekit

Tags: xcode, swift3, sprite-kit

In normal swift, you can use something like this:

```
Foundation.Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3.0, target: self, selector: #selector(GameViewController.hideFunc), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

My question is what can you replace this with to work in a Sprite kit game?

Comment: This [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46534588/modify-property-on-sknode-while-moving) might help.

Comment: @MarkBrownsword does this being marked as a duplicate mean it's going to get deleted after a while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could build it pretty easily using SKActions:

```
    let pauser = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3.0)
    let trigger = SKAction.perform(#selector(GameViewController.hideFunc, onTarget: self)
    let pauseThenTrigger = SKAction.sequence([ pauser, trigger ])
    let repeatForever = SKAction.repeatForever(pauseThenTrigger)
    node.run( repeatForever )
```

This approach would have the virtue of letting you reuse this action for any nodes that would need to use it, and you can easily control the action by removing or adding the node from the scene, calling removeAllActions() on it, etc.